# Android Device Monitor cannot access sdcard

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

I'm using Android Studio(1.4.0)

I connected Nexus5 with Android5.1 and started genymotion with android 5.0, the Android Device Monitor cannot open sdcard file folder.There is no child folder.

But when I started genymotion with android 4.1,everything is OK.